# Rootweb does not return site administrators

Tags: administration

I have multiple sites where I have used site settings to add users to 'Site Collection Administrators' but when I get these site collections using code the 'SiteAdministrators' property returns null.

Powershell example

```
 $web =get-spweb "..."
 $web
 # returns vaild web

 $web.Site.RootWeb.siteadministrators
 #returns null

  $web.Site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators.Add($user)
  #Error: cannot call method on null-valued expression
```

Solved it.
     For some reason when I run powershell my account is being given a different loginName which does not match the site collection administrators. I have changed this & I am receiving the correct information. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Can you see any site administrator listed through UI ?

Comment: Yes, users are listed in the ui. Both "site settings -> site collection administrators" and "site settings -> site permissions ->site collection administrators"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that $web is not null and that the URL being requested by Get-SPWeb resolves to a SharePoint site

Comment: Yes I am using a valid spweb

Comment: Do you have values for `$web.Site.Owner` and `$web.Site.SecondaryContact`?

Comment: When I look at the site collection using CA, yes. When I use powershell, no but the $web object is valid and I am running poweshell 'as administrator'.  Out of the 3 sites I am testing with 1 had returned values originally but no longer